# Associative property inside functional dependancy

Tags: database-design

I have a simple question regarding functional dependancy.. is AB --> C the same as BA --> C? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  **AB** in AB --> C really means A **and** B functionally determine C.  **And**, which is the truth functional operator of [**conjunction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), is associative.  Section 4 of the linked article presents the algebraic properties of conjunction.  Therefore A and B is equivalent to B and A.